# Is the code C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I know the code below used to be C, however, I wrote it in visual studio 2008 as a c++ program and it works fine (it is saved as C++).  However, the program is in C code, correct? (or is it?).

So, when I tried to compile it inside Visual Studio as C (Go to-> Properties of file -> c/c++ ->Advanced -> Compile as -> changed it to 'Compile as C code') I then get many errors, the main of which it does not recognize the LPSTR type.  So, I guess my question is: **is it C or C++ code** and if it is C, why did it not work when I changed it to compile C code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(VOID)
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    //allocate memory
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));


    //create child process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
                L"C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe",
                NULL,
                NULL,
                FALSE,
                0,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &si,
                &pi))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "create process failed");

        return -1;
    }

    //parent waits for child to complete
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    printf("Child Complete");

    //close handle
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hthread);

}
```

Comment: One way to be sure if it's C or C++ is to compile it with a C or C++ compiler with the pedantic flag on. That will eliminate any compiler extensions or other compiler irregularities that would allow non-standard C or C++ to compile.

Answer (score 6):

**It compiles cleanly as C**. The only error is triggered by `CloseHandle(pi.hthread)`, since it's not a member of `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. You're looking for `hThread` (capital T).

Answer (score 1):

It's C. But most C++ compilers are capable compiling C code. The header `conio.h` is not a part of standard C so you may want to avoid that.

`LPSTR` is defined in windows.h and since you have included it, it shouldn't give any error. It is typedef'ed:

```
typedef char* PSTR, *LPSTR;
```

For other typedef'ed variables in your code, you have to check if their headers. Try including `Winbase.h`

Comment: Neither is `windows.h` part of standard C, but I fear if he tries to avoid that, it'll get a bit complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what you give we can't see if it is valid C because you are using non-standard headers and macros. But I can imagine that there could be macro definitions that turns this into C code.

*If* it is C, it is not so good one, and not so good one for C++ either. Both languages have their way of initializing variables, but your code uses none of them. In particular in C (and for PODs in C++) there are initializers for initializing variables. Supposing that both ugly macros here expand to types:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
```

of if you have a C99 compliant compiler the first would even better be

```
STARTUPINFO si = { .cb = sizeof si };
```

If for some reason you'd need a function to zero out a whole block of memory, better use the standard function `memset` for that. But if you use the correct initializers in C (or constructors in C++) you should rarely need that explicitly.

Answer (score -7):

every c code is a valid c++ code. but its not the other way around. So if you want to use OS api's which are c++ then you should compile it as c++.

Comment: Not entirely true. C++ has additional keywords that C doesn't, C code can use those keywords as legitimate variable names. And there are other differences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: that's what i've said. c++ is a "superset" of c. that means a c code is also a c++ code. but a c++ code is not always a c code.

Comment: No, C++ is not a strict superset of C, just like the link I gave you says.

Comment: thank's for the link. I didn't know that. not much of a c++ guy myself. community driven q&a, mailing list etc brings out a primitive "being wise" syndrome i guess :)

Comment: No, C definitely won't always compile as C++. The first example I can think of is `int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: No, there are a non-trivial number of legal C programs that are *not* legal C++ programs (anything involving VLAs, implicit conversions of `void *` to other pointer types, any code that uses C++ keywords such as `class` or `new` as identifiers, etc.), and that gap gets wider with each new language version.  C and C++ are two *completely different languages* that share a large subset of syntax, but then so do Oberon and Pascal.

Comment: This perfectly valid C code will never compile with a C++ compiler: `typedef int *class; class new; new = malloc(sizeof *new); /* ... */`